# Angularjs $scope is not working as I expected, why is that?

Tags: angularjs-scope

I'm just giving my first steps on AngularJs and I have a question that maybe you can help to understand the reason for the result I'm having.
Here is the link for jsBin to make it simpler to understand: https://jsbin.com/fososikosi/edit?html,js,output

Inside the input box if I write "person" it will display (inside H2) the greeting info, that should be "false". And when I click on "say hello" the H2 content will be updated. So far so good.

But instead writing "person" inside the input, let's put "person.name".
Obviously the name won't be displayed since it's not associated to "person" on ParentController.
But then, i click on "say hello", and that info is not updated on H2(it stays blank). My question is, Why? Because if i erase and write again "person.name" it will be displayed correctly. And how could I make it to be updated just like the way I was expecting?

Hope I was clear, thank you =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be as much a scope problem as a watch issue.  The only way for the `h2` element to change is if `parsedExpr` changes.  However, that only happens inside the `$watch`.  When you click  "Say Hello" `person.name` *is* being updated, but since the watch is based on`expr`, and `expr` is not changing, the watch doesn't fire, and the `h2` element isn't updated.  To fix it, you'll need to fire the watch somehow, or move the code inside the watch into a function (on the parent controller would be best) and and call it from `sayHello()`.